# How can I run a Perl script automatically after a Ubuntu server has booted up?

Tags: linux

I wrote a Perl script which will serve as a daemon, so I'd like to let the OS (in my case, Ubuntu Linux) automatically run my Perl script after it has booted up.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a shell script wrapper for your perl script

```
#!/bin/sh - script.sh
# your perl program goes here

/bin/perl /path/to/foobar.pl
```

Make sure that you have given executable permission using

```
  chmod +x script.sh
```

and execute the following,

```
sudo update-rc.d script.sh defaults
```

This will run perl script on each startup.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a bit in the last 7 years.  In Ubuntu 16.04, the path to perl is different.  Also, you are required to supply [a bunch of configuration information](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/insserv.8.html) in your /etc/init.d/foobar.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh foobar.sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          foobar
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: forbarsvr
# Description:       foobar daemon for widget serving
### END INIT INFO
sudo -u foobarusr perl /path/to/foobar.pl &
```

This form of invoking perl allows you to run as a user (giving a constrained security domain) rather than root; to run as root, remove the `-u foobarusr`. If you are executing as a non-root user, ensure that user has permissions over all required resources, such as the perl script itself.

The trailing `&` fires off your perl script as an on-going (until finishing) task; deamon-like if it doesn't terminate for whatever reason.

Make your foobar launcher executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/foobar.sh
```

Add your script into the startup sequence:

```
sudo update-rc.d foobar.sh defaults
```

Note there is no path supplied to the script.